# backbone.js - call router.navigate but update the hash only?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'd like to call Backbone's [router.navigate](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Router-navigate) and have it update the hash fragment only, even in browsers that do support the History API. Is this possible?

For example, say I have the call:

```
router.navigate("page/" + pageNumber);
```

I'd like this to go to `#page/14` even in browsers that do support the History API and are theoretically capable of navigating to `/page/14`.

Is there an option I can set to call this? Alternatively, I guess I can just update `location.hash` manually, but I would prefer to do things through Backbone if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replacing your Backbone.History.start() with this :

```
Backbone.History.start({pushState : false});
```

Will make your Backbone application with hashes. But you'll need to add "/#/page/14" to every href of your links, to make this work!

Comment: Thanks - so this needs to be an application-wide setting, I can't set an update-hash-only preference on individual events?

Comment: In this mode catalyst uses "/#/" for routing ... if you pass any other "/page/1234/" ( without # at the beginning ) it passes directly to your browser and loads the page as a new request. If you want to route something to the router, with this, you need to use "#" in front of it.